# Using awk to calculate an average of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, math, awk, putty

I have a file named `test.txt` with the following:

```
10
200
3000
=======
4
5
=======
```

I need to write an awk script to take the text in this file as input into the awk script and output:

```
10
200
3000

Average 1070.00

4
5

Average 4.50
```

I wrote my script  like this:

```
{while($1!~"=======") s+=$1;}
{print "Average ", s}
```

Every time I run this code, I use:

```
awk -f awrp4 test.txt
```

But it crashes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner and trying to learn about the awk function so I apologize if this seems rather simple. Any help is welcome.

Comment: How do you mean it "crashes"? You rarely need a while loop in awk because it's designed to go through a file line by line. Also you're not doing any division to find your average.

Comment: It crashes because `while($1!~"=======") s+=$1;` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk, you can write:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {FS = "\n"; RS = "\n=+\n"}
    NF > 0 {
        sum = 0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            print $i
            sum += $i
        }
        printf "Average %.2f\n", sum/NF
    }
' file
```

Comment: Observation: while the data is bunches of 2 or 3 lines at a time, there's no problem with collecting all the lines at once.  If the data is in bunches of millions of lines at a time, then this requires more memory than a line-by-line approach.  However, you then also have to start worrying about whether overflow is an issue (probably not; `awk` will change to `double` from integer) and so on.  These days, few desktop or server machines will be seriously inconvenienced by even a few gigabytes of numbers in a block, so it is mostly a theoretical rather than practical objection.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly nothing wrong with Glenn's solution, but it might be a bit advanced for you. Maybe this is better suited:

```
{
if ($1 == "=======") {
    print "\nAverage " s/i "\n";
    s=0;
    i=0;
} else {
    print $1;
    s += $1;
    i += 1;
}
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, the nature of `awk` is to loop through every line of a text file. Unless you're doing some post-processing or working with arrays, a `while` loop probably isn't of much use.

Comment: Make sure you check that $1 exists before you increment `i`

Comment: The sample data doesn't include any blanks lines, so I didn't want to include any unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1~/^[[:digit:]]/ {i++; sum+=$1; print $1} $1!~/[[:digit:]]/ {print "Average", sum/i; sum=0;i=0}' file
```

- The first part checks if the first character from column 1 is a digit, if so then increment the counter 'i' and add that record(number) to sum.
- The second part is to skip any record that does not start with a digit, and then you print the average by dividing sum/i, finally reset counter and sum to 0.